# How to keep child's stdout open after parent's termination in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to run a child process from the parent app in Ubuntu. Both are C programs. The parent uses fork() with subsequent execl(), then waits for ~1 sec and terminates. The idea is to let parent terminate in a regular way, and keep child alive and running in the same console. So, the child begins to print some output with intervals of 300 ms, and I can see it for about the time while parent is alive. Then parent terminates, and further child output can not be seen in the console.

From what I have read to this moment, it seems that since the child shares all the handles, upon parent's exit stdout gets closed for both parent and child. So, I guess the child has to somehow preserve binding to the same console it was bound to upon its start. Please, advice how to achieve this.

Comment: Have your tried this to see for yourself what happens?

Comment: I'm not sure what even to try... I checked that output stops when parent's /proc/<ppid>/stat vanishes. If I write to file (instead of stdout), the output is there long after parent stops. So the child is running. But I don't know how to deal with that terminal binding stuff, or whatever is needed here to be done. It's why I'm asking what to try...

Comment: Normally the parent exiting has no effect on the child and it will continue to run and output to the terminal.  You have to go to major complex effort to avoid that and stop the child.

Comment: `The parent uses fork() with subsequent execl(),` Code speaks 1000 words. Please show the real code, not a description of it. `upon parent's exit stdout gets closed for both parent and child.` No, that's wrong. Please create and share an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you guys and thank you all for your comments! As a windows-backgrounded person I just was not sure what should be normal behaviour in such a scenario.

While building and trying out the example, I think I understood the reason of this behaviour. The problem was that I ran it in mc with panels shown. Now, I have tried to run it under different conditions, and have the following picture: if I run it from bare console, it works fine; if I run it from mc with panels hidden, it runs OK either. The only case when it stops to show output after parent had closed is when I run it with panels shown. Now it's obvious to me that in this case the mc prints "Press any key to continue..." message right upon the parent's termination and stops showing any further output from the child.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special if you want the child process to keep running and writing to the terminal, even after the parent has stopped. Try the program below. This BTW is super annoying as the child process will trash you current terminal session.

This works because:

- The child process gets a **copy** of the parents open file descriptors, including `stdout`. This is AFAIK the same as what `dup()` does.
- To actually close the file, you have to close all associated file descriptors.

See the man pages for [`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`dup()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) for more information.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int wstatus;
    switch (pid)
    {
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "fork() failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case 0:
            while (1)
            {
                printf("child working...\n");
                sleep(1);
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("Press ENTER to exit parent...\n");
            getchar();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing I've started from. This does not work for me because the executable file doesn't get unlocked if parent terminates earlier than the child. I will try to build and post here a simple example.

Comment: Btw, in this version I can see child's output after parent's termination, there's no problem here.